# how can I run a java application as daemon?

Tags: centos, daemon

I use to run an application in CentOS with the command

```
 nohup java -jar AnalyticsBackend.jar &
```

Now I want to run this application as daemon i.e. on reboot, this application shoud start running automatically. How can I do this ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Daemonizing` an application is not identical to `starting it at boot`. If all you want is to have it start automatically at boot, read on; otherwise, somewhat more complex instructions will have to be provided, or, better still, you should look up how to configure your own service.

To start a program automatically at boot, issue the command

```
  EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

(if you don't like vi as an editor put whatever you like in its stead) then add the following line:

```
  @reboot /home/myname/bin/myscript
```

Save, edit the file /home/myname/bin/myscript and put into it the following lines:

```
  #!/bin/sh

 nohup java -jar Analyticsbackend.jar
```

Save, make the file executable,

```
 chmod 755 /home/mynmae/bin/myscript, reboot, you are done.
```